# Aprendendo Flexbox e querendo entender um comportamento do meu código

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Opa, tudo bem?
Eu comecei tem um tempo a estudar html/css/js então eu ainda estou aprendendo e estou com uma certa dificuldade pra entender o porquê de um comportamento aqui.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 20vh;
    width: auto;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.header-nav{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    order: 0;
}

.header-foto{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;    
    color: black;
}

.container{
    background-color: #cacaca;
    height: 70vh;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}   

.item{
    background-color: #ff0037;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
}

.items-1{
    height: 50%;
    width: 30%;
}

.items-2{
    height: 50%;
    width: 30%;
}

.items-3{    
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
}

.items-4{
    align-self: flex-end;
    height: 50%;
    width: 30%;
}

.items-5{
    align-self: flex-start;
    height: 50%;
    width: 30%;
}

.footer{
    height: 10vh;
    width: auto;
    background-color: orange;

}

.footer-nav{
    
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-nav">nav</div>
    <div class="header-foto">foto</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="items-1 item">1</div>
    <div class="items-2 item">2</div>
    <div class="items-3 item">3</div>
    <div class="items-4 item">4</div>
    <div class="items-5 item">5</div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-nav">footer navegacao</div>
</footer>
```

https://codepen.io/fabreduarte/pen/jOYzqzG

esse é o código.
O que eu não compreendo é porque quando eu adiciono margin aos itens do elemento container elas estouram, eu gostaria que elas ficassem alinhadas assim como ficam sem a margem

[image: imagem de exemplo]

Porque acontece isso? Porque os elementos se empurram e não continuam da mesma forma apenas com a margem aplicada?

Comment: Porque, ao colocar a margem, o tamanho dos itens supera o tamanho do container, o que causa o _wrap_. Como não há espaço pra colocar 2 itens na mesma coluna e o estilo é pra alinhar no sentido vertical (`flex-direction: column`), o _wrap_ quebra o alinhamento nos itens excedentes, ficando tudo na horizontal

Comment: Eu percebi que um dos problemas era as unidades de medida que eu estava usando, eu ignorei o fato de ter colocado que meus items ocupavam já 100% do espaço do elemento pai, dai adicionando uma margem com um valor em px eu quebrei o código, porque não tem como ter 100% +2px em um espaço né.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar a propriedade gap no flex-container(o elemento com display:flex), ele faz com que coloquei um espaço entre os flex-items
por exemplo:
coloca um espaço de 32px entre os elementos(todos os lados):

```
.flex-container { display: flex; gap: 32px; }
```

para colocar apenas acima e abaixo:

```
.flex-container { display: flex; row-gap: 32px; }
```

para colocar apenas dos lados:

```
.flex-container { display: flex; column-gap: 32px; }
```